# adding fields to datasource 2LIS_12_VCITM in ECC

Tags: sap

From what I have read the datasource 2LIS_12_VCITM is built off of the ECC tables LIKP, LIPS, VBUK, and VBUP. I would like to add a couple of fields that are in the LIPS table to this datasource and am wondering on the correct way to do it. Do I simply add the fields to the extract structure of the datasource under the include section for the LIPS table?

Comment: This question will only make sense to users of SAP's Business Warehouse. As you can tell from the answer this question made perfect sense to another user of BW. Closing a question just because you don't under stand the proprietary jargon of SAP is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First look up the data source in RSA2, the field you want may be there but currently suppressed.  Lets assume it is not suppressed and you need to add it.  In RSA2 there is an extraction tab.  Copy the **Extract Structure** field from this tab.  Go to SE11 and under data type put the copied extract structure in and select change.  Under the Components tab you will see the fields that make up your datasource.  Click on **Append Structure** it is toward the top right of the screen.  You are now presented with a list of the strucutrues you can append and add your fields to.  You will have to add your field and then in the user exit **ZXRSAU01** You will need to populate them with ABAP.  Here is a link from the [SAP community.](http://scn.sap.com/thread/167373)